# In roles and server groups Manageability on windows server 2012r2 showing can not get event data

Tags: amazon-web-services, iis, amazon-ec2, iis-7

I have installed the iis roles and features on windows server 2012r2. In Roles and server Groups Getting Can not get events data.

I have tried with re-installations of iis featues.[image]